# How Can I reduce the number of routes in React js in developing dashboard?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am developing the dashboard for one of my portfolio App but due to different category and different CRUD operation,the number of routes increase and code looks become large.Can you suggest how can I manage the
different routes of dashboard.
When I click on Skill then route created(http://localhost:3000/Dashboard/Skill) now in the Skill category when I click on Edit view then again another routes create (http://localhost:3000/Dashboard/Skill/edit) Similarly more routes is creating for different Category.How Can I solve this issue.

//Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../Css/Dashboard.css'
import Menu from './Dashboard/Menu'
import About from './Dashboard/About'
import Skill from './Dashboard/Skill'
import Experience from './Dashboard/Experience'
import Header from './Dashboard/Header'
import ExperienceView from '../Components/DashboardCrud/ExperienceView'
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Switch,Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export class Dashboard extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
           redirect:false
      }

      this.logout=this.logout.bind(this);
  }

  logout()
  {
    localStorage.setItem('token','');
    localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({
        redirect:true
    })
  }
 componentWillMount()
 {
     if(localStorage.getItem('token'))
     {
         console.log("Login successs")
     }
     else{
         this.setState({
             redirect:true
         })
     }
 }

    render() {

         if(this.state.redirect)
         {
             return (<Redirect to={'/Login'}/>)
         }

        const {match}=this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
               <Header></Header>
               <div class="sidebar">
               <Link to={`${match.url}`} >Menu</Link>
               <Link to={`${match.url}/About`} >About</Link>
               <Link to={`${match.url}/Skill`} >Skill</Link>
               <Link to={`${match.url}/Experience`} >Experience</Link>
               <a onClick={this.logout} ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out</a>

               </div>


           <div class="content">

                   <Switch> 

                   <Route path={`${match.url}/Skill/edit`} component={SkillEditView}></Route>
                   <Route path={`${match.url}/Skill/delete`} component={SkillDeleteView}></Route>

                   <Route path={`${match.url}` }  exact component={Menu}></Route>
                   <Route path={`${match.url}/About`} component={About}></Route>
                   <Route path={`${match.url}/Skill`} component={Skill}></Route>
                   <Route path={`${match.url}/Experience`} component={Experience}></Route>
                   </Switch> 
            </div>


           </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Dashboard
```

// Skill.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../../Css/Dashboard/Menu.css'
import { getDashboard } from '../../Services/getDashboard'
import Load from '../../Components/Dashboard/Load'

export class Skill extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            Skills: [],
            isloading:true

        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const response = getDashboard('skill');
        response.then((sucess) => {
            this.setState({
                Skills: sucess.data,
                isloading:false
            })
            console.log(this.Abouts)
        }).catch(er => {
            console.log(er)
        })

    }

    render() {

        if(this.state.isloading)
        {
            return(
              <div className="Loader_div">
                 <Load></Load>
              </div>  
            )
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div class="container dashboard">
                    <h2 style={{ color: "red" }}>Skills Details </h2>
                    <p className="Menu_dash_desc">Edit the Skills Easily</p>
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>SkillName</th>
                                <th>value</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.Skills.map((skill) => <tr>
                                    <td>{skill.SkillName}</td>
                                    <td>{skill.value}</td>

                                    <td>


                            <Link style={{ backgroundColor: "green", border: "none" }} class="btn btn-info btn-lg" to={`${match.url}/edit/`} ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></Link>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>


                            <Link style={{ backgroundColor: "green", border: "none" }} class="btn btn-info btn-lg" to={`${match.url}/delete/`} ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></Link>

                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                                )
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Skill
```

[image: dashboard Screen]

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid this situation. For each route ('Skills', 'Experience' etc) you need to have corresponding mass of routes. And, maybe, if you route components have the same structure, better will be to create a common template and use composition.

Comment: What do you mean common template and composition?